# apply scale while keeping the height

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, objects, armature

I'm trying to parent the bones to my mesh, but it gives me the Bone heat weighting error, I figured it out that I need to make my character's scale 10 for some reason to fix that, but I want it to keep my model the same size.

So far I've tried putting the scale to 0.1, apply the scale, then putting it to 10, thus having the same size as originally, but that didn't work (I've tried with this method having only the model's scale at 10, then only the armatures's, then both)

Got any ideas? Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: what about scale x10, parent, then scale back 0.1?

Comment: Can you [share](https://blend-exchange.com/) your .blend file and put it into the question body?

Comment: Thanks Moonboots, it worked.